# Find on Excel Sheet which cells are referenced to other Sheets

Tags: excel, vba, reference

I need to locate them and substitute its formula by its value.

Currently I'm looking for `!` but I think its not very clean.

`!` could be used inside a formula without refering other sheets, i.e: `=IF(A1<0; "Be careful A1 is negative!"; "OK");`

Checking if `!` appears before `"` doesn't seem definitive solution, i.e.:
`=IF(A1<0; "Be careful A1 is negative!"; Sheet2!A1+2);`

**UPDATE:** Apart from whats explained above, named ranges should also be taken into account. They could refer other sheets without using `!`.

Answer (score 2):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub testOtherSheetsRef()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, rngF As Range, C As Range
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  Set rngF = sh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
  For Each C In rngF
    If InStr(C.Formula, "!") > 0 Then
        If InStr(C.Formula, " !") = 0 And _
            InStr(C.Formula, "! ") = 0 And _
            InStr(C.Formula, "!""") = 0 Then
            Debug.Print C.Address & " is referencing another sheet..."
        End If
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Good solution but maybe not fully safe!

Comment: @Jaime Oro: Maybe, but only in case of strings wrong spelling. The trick is that in case of a sheet reference, there is nothing in between the "!" character and the sheet name, respectively, the range. The single string case looks to be the double quotes closing the string, I think. Which is handles by the `Sub`...

Answer (score 2):

You can use Regex to find a reference in a formula to another sheet:

```
Option Explicit

Function GetFormulaReference(sFormula As String) As String
    Dim sPattern As String, sRng As String
    Dim oRegex As RegExp, oMatches As Object, oMatch As Object
        
    Debug.Print sFormula
    sPattern = "\w+!\w{1,}\d{1,}"
    Set oRegex = New RegExp
    With oRegex
        .Pattern = sPattern
        Set oMatches = .Execute(sFormula)
        For Each oMatch In oMatches
            sRng = oMatch
        Next
    End With
    Set oMatch = Nothing
    Set oMatches = Nothing
    Set oRegex = Nothing
    
    GetFormulaReference = sRng
    
End Function
```

**Usage:**

```
Sub Test()
    Dim sRng As String
    
    sRng = GetFormulaReference("=IF(A1<0; ""Be careful A1 is negative!""; ""Sheet2!A1+2"");")
    Debug.Print "Address: = '" & sRng & "'"
    sRng = GetFormulaReference("=IF(A1<0; ""Be careful A1 is negative!""; ""OK"");")
    Debug.Print "Address: = '" & sRng & "'"

End Sub
```

**Result:**

```
=IF(A1<0; "Be careful A1 is negative!"; "Sheet2!A1+2");
Address: = 'Sheet2!A1'
=IF(A1<0; "Be careful A1 is negative!"; "OK");
Address: = ''
```

**Note #1:** you need to add a reference to `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5`
**Note #2:** above pattern will work for `A1` style addressing, but not for `R1C1`!

[image: reference]

**Final note:** If `GetFormulaReference` function returns empty string, then there's no reference to another sheet.

**[EDIT]**

For [named ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.names), you can use something like this:

```
Function GetNamedRangeReference(sFormula) As String
    Dim nms As Object, sName As String, sRetVal As String
    Set nms = ActiveWorkbook.Names 
    For i = 1 To nms.Count 
        sName = nms(r).Name 
        If InStr(1, sFormula, sName, vbTextCompare)>0 Then sRetVal =  nms(r).RefersToRange.Address 'return address instead of name
    Next

    GetNamedRangeReference = sRetVal

End Function
```

**Note:** I haven't tested above function.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot. The only problem is that is not taking into account named ranges.

Comment: Maybe I could look for each defined named range from other sheets inside the formula. I'm not very good at using REGEX.
Do you know how can I find if RANGE_NAME is inside the formula? (without being inside quotes)

Comment: You didn't mention that you want to find named range inside a formula... In this case, i'll create a dictionary from named ranges collection, then loop through the cell in a sheet to find reference to that named range. But this is another requirement.

Comment: True, I found this problem when trying tour code. The only thing Noe if there's something similar yo the mames Rangel between quotes.

Comment: Also if named range is SU, everytime he founds SUM() would fail.

Comment: Seems, you need to find exact match. I'd suggest to use Regex. I've not enough time to improve my answer today. If you have sample workbook and you can share it, i'll download it. Then, i'll write function in my free time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219332/discussion-between-maciej-los-and-jaime-oro).